# Run a raw SQL statement to rename an index in a Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to run the following raw SQL statement in a Laravel migration:

```
RENAME INDEX offer_venue_id_fk_idx TO offers_venue_id_index
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the facade `DB` you can run a raw SQL statement like this:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME INDEX offer_venue_id_fk_idx TO offers_venue_id_index');
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do something like `DB::table('table_name')->statement(...)`, or is that invalid?

Comment: @YahyaUddin I'm not sure, you'll have to try it, but I don't see how this may be different than the other syntax.